# In Romans 8:29 is Paul speaking of "predestination" with regard to birth or to judgment?

Tags: romans, grammar, historical-interpretation, authorial-intent

**Predestinate**: to determine or set a destiny ahead of an appointed time.

I am curious as to why the appointed time in regard to 'predestinate' is so often interpreted to mean "before time began," when a more consistent meaning in regard to salvation would be "before judgment." There is one case where predestinate is qualified as being before the foundations of the World, when talking about how being in Christ was always the plan, and it was always the plan that those in Christ would be blameless. That exception suggests to me that 'before the foundation of the World' is needed as a qualifier, and is not something to automatically assume.

**MY QUESTION:** How does one answer these questions concerning the use of predestinate when not specified:

(a) Destine what? 

(b) Ahead of what time?

**EXAMPLE**

> Rom 8:29 (KJV)
>   
>   For whom he did foreknow, [G4267] he also did predestinate [G4309] to be conformed to the image of his Son, that he might be the firstborn among many brethren.
>   
>   προορίζω proorízō, pro-or-id'-zo; from G4253 and G3724; to limit in advance, i.e. (figuratively) predetermine:—determine before, ordain, predestinate.

In Rom 8:29, how does one know whether to interpret foreknow to mean "before time began" or "before judgment" or something else? If it is "before time began," then that would mean everything is settled before you're born. If it is "before judgment," then that would point to a salvation event in the person's lifetime.

Comment: There are many different soteriologies, and you they need to be assessed against the whole of scripture. You might like to visit and ask questions like this at [christianity.se] instead.

Comment: @curiousdannii : Do you feel that this is not a reasonable Hermeneutics question as posed in MY QUESTION? If not, perhaps you can suggest a simple modification that would allow the question to fit into the context of this site?

Comment: @TrialAndError This is actually a Very Good Question and it strikes at the heart of predestination. An Omniscient God knows everything-otherwise by definition He cannot be "God". And He lives outside of our space/time continuum, therefore He can be both Alpha And Omega. Yet, when He 'communicates' this knowledge before the actual event, it changes 'destiny', even though He equips man with a will to chose. Does the very act of knowing deprive choice....? This is at the heart of predestination.

Comment: @TrialAndError - Per dannii's comment, I'd suggest the first 3/4 of your question is mostly hermeneutical (in scope), and the last bit is mostly doctrinal (out of scope). As we're a hermeneutics site, the context is always 'how do we interpret the text', and not 'is X interpretation/doctrine consistent' - because [this is not a Christian site](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/441/423), and we're all about the meaning of the text. Logical arguments involving implications are relevant and can *partly* inform our hermeneutic of interpretation, but don't supersede authorial intent.

Comment: TrialAndError (great pen name), I like your question and agree that the last bit should be left off. But I wanted to inform/remind you that you are allowed to answer your own question. It sounds like you may have done some study on this and if so, great, feel free to post your answer and mark it so.

Comment: @Ruminator , does my newly edited question address some of your concerns?

Comment: @TrialAndError  Sorry to just be getting back to you; I didn't see this. In my opinion, the question is fine as it stands now. +1

Comment: @TrialAndError Actually, as I look at it some more I don't see anything special about verbs of "knowing before" or "predetermining" that require a special hermeneutic. I think it would be better to make this question about how to interpret the Romans verse and in that process the hermeneutic will be discussed as well. Would you like me to edit your question?

Comment: The question title is fine but the body of the question vacillates between a question about the verse and a question of a hermeneutic.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that we can answer your question by using some help from Ephesians 1.

Ephesians 1:4

> According as he hath chosen us in him ***before*** the **foundation of the
>   world**, that we should be holy and without blame before him in love:

This verse clearly communicates that we (believers) have been chosen in Christ before the foundation of the world. The word foundation in Greek (KATABOLE) clearly expresses that this is a time reference, ie before that (foundation) which is laid down.

**KATABOLE**

> Vines: “lit. a casting down is used (b) of a foundation as that which
>   is laid down or in the sense of founding, metaphorically, of the
>   foundation of the world, in this respect two phrases are used (2)
>   “before the foundation of the world”, John 17:24, Eph 1:4, 1 Pet 1:20.
>   The latter phrase looks back into past eternity.”

The same message is being communicated in Romans 8:29.

> 29 For whom he did foreknow, he also did **predestinate** to be conformed
>   to the image of his Son, that he might be the firstborn among many
>   brethren

The word predestinate in Greek (PROORIZO) gives you the understanding that the believer was conformed to the image of His Son before the foundation of the world, meaning, looking back past the visible horizon, that which is clearly marked out: foreordained.

**PROORIZO**

> Vines:“*pro*, beforehand and No. 2 (HORIZO) denotes to mark out
>   beforehand, to determine before, foreordain…”

**HORIZO**

> Vines: “denotes to bound, to set a boundary(Eng. horizon) hence to
>   mark out definitely, determine; it is translated to determine in Luke
>   22:22, of the fore-ordained pathway of Christ…”

Comment: I agree that those in Christ are pre-destined. They are destined ahead of time for salvation. That did not happen to believers before the World began. "And you also were included in Christ *when* you heard the message of truth, the gospel of your salvation. *When you believed*, you were marked in him with a seal, the promised Holy Spirit, who is a deposit guaranteeing our inheritance until the redemption of those who are God’s possession—to the praise of his glory." The plan was in place at the beginning for those who would be in Christ.

Comment: Understand your feeling but I see no conflict here. The Greek is pretty clear. Verses 4-11 talk specifically about being predestined/preordained and verse 13 is just the fulfilment of that which God has willed, ie verse 13 is just a playing out of God's will. Please notice the words "also" (KJV) in the verse. Verses 4-11 state that you were in Christ before the world began and then you "also"  believed and trusted in Him to receive the seal of the Holy Spirit. The plan was in  place before the world was formed and we just executed according to plan.

Comment: Yes, the plan was always that those in Christ would be held blameless. It was the place that was fore-ordained. Those in Christ. But we weren't always blameless, and we have not always been in Christ, as evidenced by the description of when we are included in Christ: we are included in Christ when we hear the Gospel, and believe.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking: what is the difference between being preordained "before" the world was formed (as specified in Ephesians 1:4) and being preordained "after" the world was formed but before the Christian's profession of faith?

Comment: If it were determined before time began who would be saved and who would not, then the event of Christ coming to this Earth would be irrelevant. In Ephesians 1, "And you also were included in Christ when you heard the message of truth, the gospel of your salvation. When you believed, you were marked in him with a seal, the promised Holy Spirit, who is a deposit guaranteeing our inheritance until the redemption of those who are God’s possession—to the praise of his glory." Pre-ordained in this sense has to do with receiving and believing the Gospel message. That's different.

Comment: Again, understand you're feeling as this is exactly how I felt years ago where I believed that sanctification was a process and I participated with God to in my  becoming holy. However, that's not what scripture says. Salvation, repentance and sanctification are all gifts of God. If you'd like we can start a chat to discuss further. God bless.

Comment: What you are discussing now is more a question of feeling than it is about the meaning conveyed by the words.

Comment: I really don't want to argue but the Greek is clear, "chosen in Him BEFORE the foundation of the world".  You need to harmonize all verses.

Comment: akberardis@comcast.net if you'd like to discuss further. God bless.

Comment: Ususally the debate over predestination isn't a matter of time (before the World began) .  The usually debate is whether predestination applies to each individual being predestined versus salvation being predestined.  The real problem is finite human logic that sees a conflict between predestination and human responsibility/choice.

Answer (score 0):

My question is, did God predestine man saved before man believed and trusted in the lord for salvation, meaning that some are chosen by God to be saved and others are not? Jesus said that his desire was that all people would be saved,but that no man cometh unto the father except through him (Jesus)! Is there a misinterpretation of the word predestinated or a misunderstanding of the word predestinated! Ephesians 2:8-9 says For by Grace are you saved through faith and that not of yourselves lest any man should boast! That’s a decision a person has to make! To me predestinated would mean your saved before your born whether you believe or not! And I know this is not so, because with the heart man believeth unto righteousness!

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/51254)

Comment: @ Mark - The questions you ask are good questions. However it is not the place to "ask questions" in someone else's posted question. But rather post your own question(s). Only "answers" should be proffered here. Keep studying the Bible; it's great for the soul!

Answer (score 0):

Part I - **God’s Omniscience vs. Man’s Free Will**

This is a problem of philosophy and hence a big problem for philosophers. The issue goes something like this:

**Philosophical Issue**

God, since He is God, is “*bound*” to know everything in advance. For example, God knew in advance (because He “*has to be*” omniscient) that Adam and Eve would sin. Yet, God gave them free will to choose between the two trees.

So, did God foreknow that Adam was going to sin?

Yes, of course, because He “*has to be*” omniscient.

But, was Adam really “*free*” to choose between one tree or the other?

Yes, of course, because he was given free will.

It is simple logic that both cannot be correct at the same time! If God knew in advance that Adam was going to sin, then Adam has to be “***automated***” to sin. If Adam was really free to choose, that is, if he had real free will, then God didn’t know in advance that Adam was going to sin.

**Scriptural Answer**

It is my opinion that if we wish to receive the truth then we need to separate Scripture from philosophy. Apostle Paul warns us:

> “Watch that there not be one robbing you **through philosophy** and
> empty deceit, according to **the tradition of men**, according to the
> elements of the world, and not according to Christ” (Col 2:8).

If God is omniscient, then God is omnipotent also. In His omnipotence, what if God has Willed (decided) not to know in advance whether Adam would sin or not?

Who will or can “*limit*” God in His capacity? In fact, the philosophers “*limit*” God when they say that God “*has to*” know or God “*is bound*” to know everything in advance.

They make God into a **“helpless” Almighty** (what an oxymoron!)!

Man dictates to God saying, an Omniscient God ***should*** know everything in advance as otherwise, by definition, He cannot be God!

But the true living God says:

> “They have built altars to Baal in Hinnom Valley, to sacrifice their
> sons and daughters to the god Molech. I did not command them to do
> this, **and it did not even enter my mind** that they would do such a
> thing and make the people of Judah sin" (Jeremiah 32:35; GNB).

There it is! God says that He **never knew** that they would do such a detestable thing!!

Where is man’s philosophy and where is God’s Word?!

**The Scriptural Truth**

It is true that God is all-knowing. Jesus Himself teaches that in Matthew 10:29.

But when God created man and gave him free will, God Willed (decided) that He does not want to know in advance what man was going to do (unless, of course, He had some specific task to do like He hardened the heart of Pharaoh or forced Balaam’s curse into blessing etc).

So, the truth is, God didn’t want to foreknow whether Adam would sin or not. So, Adam had **genuine free will** and his action was solely *his own decision*.

But God knew the possibilities and He had planned the options in advance. I can think of 4 possibilities:

- Possibility 1 – Adam and Eve do not sin: God’s Plan A to be executed;
- Possibility 2 – Adam sins but Eve doesn’t sin: God’s Plan B to be executed;
- Possibility 3 – Adam doesn’t sin but Eve sins: God’s Plan C to be executed; and
- Possibility 4 – Adam and Eve both sin: God’s Plan D to be executed.

Today we know that it was the fourth possibility that really took place and immediately God implemented His foreordained option D as is explained in Revelation 13:8 and 1 Peter 1:19-20.

Part II - **God’s Predestination vs. Man’s Free Will**

This is another problem for the philosophers, which is made into “isms” like Calvinism etc.

The philosophical problem is: if God has predestinated some to be saved and some to be damned eternally, how does man’s free will work?

This time the philosophers make man into a “helpless creature” (it seems philosophers make everyone helpless)! He has free will to make choice, yet God foreknew who would go to heaven and who would go to hell.

Again, logically we know that both cannot be correct. Either God foreknew who would go where, and man is “*automated*”, or man has real and genuine free will and God does not Will to know who will go where.

**What Scripture Says**

> “to those **being called** according to purpose; because whom He
> **foreknew**, He also **predestinated to be** conformed to the image of His Son, for Him to be the First-born among many brothers. But whom
> He predestinated, these He also **called**; and whom He called, these
> He also **justified**; and whom He justified, these He also
> **glorified**” (Rom 8:28).

The order is as follows (it is talking only about “those being called”):

Foreknowledge --> predestination --> calling --> justification --> glorification.

- ***Foreknowledge***:- God knew in advance whoever He was going to call to His purpose. This is what Jesus meant when He said that no one could come to Him unless God the Father drew him (John 6:44). (There is no implication here that the persons thus drawn by Father end up automatically in heaven).
- ***Predestination***:- This is only an appointment fixed earlier for a specific purpose. For example we can say that God “predestinated” Adam and Eve to be the first parents to be created. God “predestinated” them to make a choice between two trees. But, in spite of such “predestination” both of them **failed** in the task! So, again, predestination does not mean some one automatically ends up in heaven.

God’s predestination is a prior appointment for a purpose. What is that purpose? “To be conformed to the image of His Son”.

- ***Calling***:- Now comes the practical side of all this - the **real action** taken by God. As Jesus said, the Father draws the person to Jesus.

Consider the case of Moses. God foreknew Moses long before. God predestinated Moses to a purpose of freeing the slave children of Israel from Egypt (also to be conformed to the image of Christ). But the actual “**calling**” came only when Moses was 80 years of age at the burning bush.

Or consider the case of Saul aka Paul. God foreknew Saul long before. He predestinated Saul to take the gospel of Jesus Christ to the Gentiles (also to be conformed to the image of Christ). But, again, the actual “**calling**” came only later on the road to Damascus.

Here again, there is no hint of such a called person automatically ending up in heaven!

**Conclusion**

God “*foreknew*” all human beings because He is the Creator of them all. God has already “*predestinated*” them all to be conformed to the image of His Son (John 3:16).

But God actually “*called*” a “remnant” (both from Israel and Gentiles) in the “present time” (Rom 11:5) and “hardened the rest” (verse 7). But God will “*call*” ALL in the coming age, when He will “show mercy to ALL” (verse 32).

So, predestination does not mean that the person automatically ends up saved in heaven. A great deal depends on the positive response from that person to God’s actual call.